What if one derivative is linearly dependent to another group of derivatives?
Suppose for vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, scalar functions $q(\mathbf{x})$ and $r_1(\mathbf{x}), \dots, r_m(\mathbf{x})$, there exist $f_1(\mathbf{x}), \dots, f_m(\mathbf{x})$ such that this holds for all $\mathbf{x}$:
$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = f_1(\mathbf{x}) \frac{\partial r_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}} + \dots + f_m(\mathbf{x}) \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \:,
$$
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ means taking the gradient.
What does it say about the functions $q$ and $r_i$? It is tempting to say that $q$ is a function of $r_i$ and that $f_i$ is just $\frac{\partial q}{\partial r_i}$, except it does not guarantee this. For $f_i = \frac{\partial q}{\partial r_i}$ to happen, one must have
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial r_j} = \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial r_i}, \quad \forall i\neq j \:.
$$
So, generally speaking, what can we say about $q$ and $r_i$? I feel like it has something to do with differential manifolds but I lack expertise in it.

This is what happens when you use meaningless notation. What does $\partial f/\partial r_j$ even mean? The $f_i$ are functions of $\mathbf x$. The correct necessary (and, locally, sufficient) condition is that $d\left(\sum f_i,dr_i\right) = \sum df_i\wedge dr_i = 0$.

To be explicit, this is the condition that $\sum_i\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j},\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial x_k} -\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k},\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial x_j}  = 0$ for all $j,k$.

You can more naturally rewrite your question using differential forms as
$$dq = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i\,dr_i.$$
If $dr_1,\dots,dr_m$ are linearly independent, i.e., if $dr_1\wedge\dots\wedge dr_m\ne 0$, then, indeed, we can think of $r_1,\dots,r_m$ as independent "variables" (i.e., coordinate functions) which form part of a local coordinate system $y_1,\dots,y_m,y_{m+1},\dots,y_n$ on an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Then, indeed, it follows that $q$, written in the $y$ variables, is just a function of $y_1,\dots,y_m$.
As I commented above, a necessary (and locally sufficient) condition that we can write $q$ in this way is that $d(dq) = 0$, and so we need $\sum df_i\wedge dr_i = 0$. You also should have the independence condition on the $dr_i$ stated explicitly.

Thank you, I like this answer very much. But the original intention of this post was to ask what is the general condition we can draw here, regardless of whether $\sum df_i \wedge dr_i = 0$?

That condition must hold, since $d(dq)=0$. You cannot have arbitrary functions $f_i$ and $r_i$.
